# Unique Value For Custom Attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom-attributes

I created one custom attibute for customer. and make unique value true. 
while we edit customer in admin panel , and trying to save, its always give error like attribute should be unique. but their value is already unique.

I created the attribute like this:

```
if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.9','<')) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_number', [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Mobile Number',
                'input' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'unique' => true,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'position' => 112,
                'system' => 0,
                'source' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_number')
        ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit'],

        ]);

        $attribute->save();
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please mention which magento version you are using because i found it is known bug and get resolved in magento 2.2.x

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7844

Comment: I am using magento 2.1.5